# Add padding to a CSS3 Flebox item

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to add a fixed padding to an element inside a flexbox layout.
The problem is that the padding enlarges the element size, as if no `box-sizing: border-box` was applied.

Here is an exemple Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nuzBd

Any hint on why is this happening?

Comment: `box-sizing: padding-box;` maybe.

Comment: @TylerH it works only in FF

Comment: Have you tried adding `-webkit-box-sizing` and `-moz-box-sizing`?